# Replacing a value in a file using Shell Scripting

Tags: shell

I want to replace a string in linux file with a variable value using Shell Script:
Tried doing this in shell script, but not working.

`sed -i "s/$StrVal1/$StrVal2/" "$TargetFile"`

Please help.

Comment: Be more specific. What was the output expected, what error message did you get,...

Comment: If either string contains slashes, for instance, problems would completely be expected -- but the question needs to include enough information to know if that's the case; as it is, it simply contains insufficient details to be answerable. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ...a better formulation of this question would include the actual file contents being edited (or, if those contents are confidential, other contents tested to be adequate to reproduce the issue), and specific `StrVal1` and `StrVal2` values likewise tested to reproduce the problem. And instead of "not working", it would describe **precisely how** it failed to work: With an error message? A successful status, but no changes to the file? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the "g" in the sed command. Works for me on my linux shell. You can also cat the file and then run the sed command.

First I define variables as shown below, on the prompt:

```
   a='class'; b='CLASS'
```

Then I cat the file with a sed command:

```
   cat a.txt | sed "s/$a/$b/g"
```

So my input file is like

```
   class="pending">Count
   class="completed">Count
```

My output with that command is like

```
   CLASS="pending">Count:
   CLASS="completed">Count:
```